# Time machine drive wiped?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, ssd

I backed up an old laptop via Time Machine to an SSD ~1 year ago.
Now, I'm trying to browse/restore the files on that SSD, but when I connect the SSD to my current (OSX) laptop, it is not recognized as anything special at all!

I see what you would expect when connecting this Samsung T5 drive for the first time: an empty file system except for Samsung's own programs. However, the size of the drive is only 44MB (down from a listed size of 500GB).

I'm not sure what's going on here, any ideas?

Comment: did you verify the back up ? what was the OS on old laptop and what is it on new laptop

Comment: @Ruskes I only verified the backup through Time Machine itself (as opposed to loading on another computer). Old = Monterey, New = Ventura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was my fault. I stupidly put the Time Machine backup behind Samsung's horrendous password protection.

Of course, the drivers didn't work on macOS for some reason so I had to load it on Windows, disable the security, then I could load it.